# How to match every char except slash .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, preg-match

I'm trying to make .htaccess expression . How can I make preg to say to match every correcter that is possible including other languages like arabic except one char which is "/" . so basically I need something like this (.*?) except "/" .How should I make that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`([^/]?)`

By putting things in a range with a `^` you say "not this stuff".